# Markdown: Syntax highlighting for code in text

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I understand that one can introduce synatx highlighting in GitHub flavored markdown for code *blocks*, so something like

````
```python
some python code
```
````

would be highlighted. Is something like this also possible for code fragments *in the text*, e.g.

```
usual text `some python code` text again
```

?
Additional question: Which common markdown flavors allow something like this, which don't?